# Extracting part of a 3-dim array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm adding functionality to an existing macro, and the updates converts a 2-dim array to a 3-dim array.

Previously, I assigned the values from the following array directly to a range:

```vb
arrMyArray(1 To 12, 1 To x)
```

I'm now asking the macro to collect additional data, and as it's related I thought I'd use the following 3-dim array to be concise:

```vb
arrMyArray(1 To 12, 1 To x, 1 To 2)
```

Is there a way to assign only `arrMyArray(1 To 12, 1 To x, 1)` to a range??

As there are 4 more arrays like the above, and x can go as high as 10, looping through individual values would take hundreds of operations, which seems inefficient.

Edit:

The arrays are populated as such:

```vb
arrMonthsMA(1) = "apr"
arrMonthsMA(2) = "may"
arrMonthsMA(3) = "jun"
arrMonthsMA(4) = "jul"
arrMonthsMA(5) = "aug"
arrMonthsMA(6) = "sep"
arrMonthsMA(7) = "oct"
arrMonthsMA(8) = "nov"
arrMonthsMA(9) = "dec"
arrMonthsMA(10) = "jan"
arrMonthsMA(11) = "feb"
arrMonthsMA(12) = "mar"

arrYearsMA(1) = arrYearOneMA
arrYearsMA(2) = arrYearTwoMA
arrYearsMA(3) = arrYearThreeMA
arrYearsMA(4) = arrYearFourMA
arrYearsMA(5) = arrYearFiveMA

For i = 1 To UBound(arrYearsMA())
    For j = 1 To iNumberOfAccountsMA
        For k = 1 To 12 'The months
            'Transaction values
            If iCount = 0 Then sSearch = "cy" & "_" & arrMonthsMA(k) & "_transaction_value"
            If iCount <> 0 Then sSearch = "cy" & iCount & "_" & arrMonthsMA(k) & "_transaction_value"
                            
            Set rngToFind = .Cells.Find(what:=sSearch, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns)
            arrYearsMA(i)(k, j, 1) = rngToFind.Offset(, j).Value2
                            
            'Transaction count
            If iCount = 0 Then sSearch = "cy" & "_" & arrMonthsMA(k) & "_transaction_count"
            If iCount <> 0 Then sSearch = "cy" & iCount & "_" & arrMonthsMA(k) & "_transaction_count"
                            
            Set rngToFind = .Cells.Find(what:=sSearch, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns)
            arrYearsMA(i)(k, j, 2) = rngToFind.Offset(, j).Value2
                            
            If k = 12 And j = iNumberOfAccountsMA Then iCount = iCount - 1 Next: Next: Next
```

The odd search string is just due to the weird labelling in the source workbook.
I would copy from the array to a range like so:

```vb
For i = 1 To UBound(arrYearsMA())
    With rngToFind.Offset((13 * iOffsetMA) + (13 * (i - 1)), 1)
        Range(.Offset(, 0), .Offset(11, iNumberOfAccountsMA - 1)).Value = arrYearsMA(i)
    End With
Next i
```

Comment: "4 more arrays like the above" - do you mean 4 x 3D arrays like `arrMyArray1(i,j,k), arrMyArray2(i,j,k), arrMyArray3(i,j,k), arrMyArray4(i,j,k)` ?

Comment: It'd probably be easier to use a jagged array here, or a dictionary or collection.

Comment: @CDP1802 Yes, each one covers a different year.

Comment: This is likely an XY problem.

Comment: You can create an array of arrays like `Dim arrMyArray(1 To 4, 1 To 2) As Variant :  arrMyArray(1, 1) = Range("A1:L10") :  Debug.Print arrMyArray(1, 1)(1, 1) 'A1 value`

Comment: I have a jagged array holding the 5 individual 3-dim arrays, and I get them as 'arrYears(1)' = Range("A1:L10")', where 'arrYears(1) = arrYearOne(1 to 12, 1 to x)'. I'm not sure how it would work to introduce another array.

Comment: It is unclear what you're trying to do. Show us the code where you're using (populating) `arrMyArray`, `arrYears`, and `arrYearOne`, and explain why you need to return all the data in a single data structure and what you plan on doing with it.

Comment: @VBasic2008 I'd edited my question with what I'm trying to do. I've aimed for a single data structure as I'd like to avoid looping through hundreds (in some cases thousands) of cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think of a 3D array as a stack of 2D arrays, you can extract a single "layer" from that stack using something like this:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    
    Dim arr(1 To 12, 1 To 10, 1 To 3) 'for example
    Dim a As Long, b As Long, c As Long
    
    'populate with some dummy data
    For a = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        For b = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
            For c = 1 To UBound(arr, 3)
                arr(a, b, c) = Join(Array(a, b, c), "~")
            Next c
        Next b
    Next a
    
    'extract data for fixed values of 3rd dimension
    LayerToSheet arr, 2, ActiveSheet.Range("C5")
    
    LayerToSheet arr, 1, ActiveSheet.Range("N5")

End Sub

'place a "layer" of a 1-based 3D array to range `c`
Sub LayerToSheet(arr, layerIndex, c As Range)
    Dim a As Long, b As Long, arrOut
    'size an array for the output (faster than cell-by-cell)
    ReDim arrOut(1 To UBound(arr, 1), 1 To UBound(arr, 2))
    For a = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)     'fill the output array
        For b = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
            arrOut(a, b) = arr(a, b, layerIndex)
        Next b
    Next a
    'put the array on the sheet from cell `c`
    c.Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)).Value = arrOut
End Sub
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! It's a shame VBA doesn't offer a native solution to the problem, but your workaround is straight-forward :D